# How to resolve the "Specified cast is not valid." error

Tags: c#, runtime-error

I have simple project, I dynamically execute a `string value` with `C# compiler`.

follow code:

```
private void btntest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string code = @"
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace myNameSpace
{
    public class DynamicClass
    {
        public bool myFunction(DataRow dr)
        {
            if (dr == null)
                return false;

            if (dr.Table.Columns.Contains(""Col1"")  && (bool)dr[""Col1""] == true)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
";

            Assembly asm = BuildAssembly(code);
            object instance = null;
            Type type = null;
            instance = asm.CreateInstance("myNameSpace.DynamicClass");
            type = instance.GetType();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Col1");
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = true;

            MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("myFunction");
            object returnVal = method.Invoke(instance, new object[] { dr });
            txtError.Text = returnVal.ToString();

        }

        Assembly BuildAssembly(string code)
        {
            CodeDomProvider codeProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
            CompilerParameters compilerparams = new CompilerParameters();
            compilerparams.GenerateExecutable = false;
            compilerparams.GenerateInMemory = false; 

            compilerparams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
            compilerparams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
            compilerparams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");
            compilerparams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.dll");

            CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerparams, code);
            if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
            {
                StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder("Compiler Errors :\r\n");
                foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
                {
                    errors.AppendFormat("Line {0},{1}\t: {2}\n",
                           error.Line, error.Column, error.ErrorText);
                }
                throw new Exception(errors.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                return results.CompiledAssembly;
            }
        }
```

when I run the project,I get the following error:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> Inner Exception
>
> InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

if I remove the `(bool)dr[""Col1""] == true` section , it's working well.

what `assembly` or `namespace` should be added?

How to fix this error?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should verify that `dr["Col1"]` is actually a bool before trying to explicitly cast it.  Try: `.. && dr[""Col1""] is bool myValue && myValue == true`

Comment: It's set in `dr[0] = true;` line;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
dt.Columns.Add("Col1");
```

If you do not specify a type, it will default to `string`. This means that the value of the cell is getting converted to a string `True`.
So you should be doing this:

```
dt.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(bool));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have already pointed out, this is the line causing the issue:

```
if (dr.Table.Columns.Contains("Col1")  && (bool)dr["Col1"] == true)
```

The explicit cast of `dr["Col1"]` to a `bool` is failing because the value is *not a boolean*.  The explicit cast fails.

Assuming that `dr["Col1"]` should actually contain a `bool` but may not always, you could verify it's type before converting using syntax like this:

```
dr["Col1"] is bool myValue && myValue == true
```

The above code verified that `dr["Col1"]` is a `bool` and then defined `myValue` as that `bool` value.

The code can become even cleaner by removing `myValue == true` and just having `myValue` (as it will be evaluated as `true` or `false`).  In your quoted code:

```
if (dr.Table.Columns.Contains(""Col1"") && dr[""Col1""] is bool myValue && myValue)
```

If `dr["Col1"]` does not actually contain a `bool` but actually contains an `int` or something else as an *indicator* of the value being true you will need to implement different logic.

Comment: thanks for attension, Dear friend, the value is set in the `dr[0] = true;` line;

Comment: @A.R.F Indeed but the value is _not_ a `bool`.  If you run `myFunction` code directly you will see that the value of `dr["Col1"]` is actually `True`.  A string that represents the `bool` value